# Why does unpacking a tuple cause a syntax error?

Tags: python, arguments, tuples

In Python, I wrote this:

```
bvar=mht.get_value()
temp=self.treemodel.insert(iter,0,(mht,False,*bvar))
```

I'm trying to expand `bvar` to the function call as arguments.
But then it returns:

```
File "./unobsoluttreemodel.py", line 65
    temp=self.treemodel.insert(iter,0,(mht,False,*bvar))
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What just happen? It should be correct right?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to pass the last argument as a tuple of `(mnt, False, bvar[0], bvar[1], ...)` you could use

```
temp = self.treemodel.insert(iter, 0, (mht,False)+tuple(bvar) )
```

---

The extended call syntax `*b` can only be used in [calling functions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls), [function arguments](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions), and [tuple unpacking](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) on Python 3.x.

```
>>> def f(a, b, *c): print(a, b, c)
... 
>>> x, *y = range(6)
>>> f(*y)
1 2 (3, 4, 5)
```

Tuple literal isn't in one of these cases, so it causes a syntax error.

```
>>> (1, *y)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target
```

Comment: Right, the `*` resolution operator is not allowed for creating tuples.

Answer (score 39):

Update: this behavior was fixed in Python 3.5.0, see [PEP-0448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

> Unpacking is proposed to be allowed inside tuple, list, set, and dictionary displays:

```
*range(4), 4
# (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

[*range(4), 4]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

{*range(4), 4}
# {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

{'x': 1, **{'y': 2}}
# {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not it isn't right. Parameters expansion works only in function arguments, not inside tuples.

```
>>> def foo(a, b, c):
...     print a, b, c
... 
>>> data = (1, 2, 3)
>>> foo(*data)
1 2 3

>>> foo((*data,))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    foo((*data,))
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have an extra level of parentheses in there. Try:

```
temp=self.treemodel.insert(iter,0,mht,False,*bvar)
```

Your extra parentheses are trying to create a tuple using the `*` syntax, which is a syntax error.