# Remove all special characters, punctuation and spaces from string

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to remove all special characters, punctuation and spaces from a string so that I only have letters and numbers.

Answer (score 554, accepted):

This can be done without regex:

```
>>> string = "Special $#! characters   spaces 888323"
>>> ''.join(e for e in string if e.isalnum())
'Specialcharactersspaces888323'
```

You can use [`str.isalnum`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum):

> ```
> S.isalnum() -> bool
>
> Return True if all characters in S are alphanumeric
> and there is at least one character in S, False otherwise.
> ```

If you insist on using regex, other solutions will do fine. However note that if it can be done without using a regular expression, that's the best way to go about it.

Comment: What is the reason not using regex as a rule of thumb?

Comment: @ChrisDutrow regex are slower than python string built-in functions

Comment: This only works when the string is in *unicode*. Otherwise it complains like 'str' object has no attribute 'isalnum' 'isnumeric' and so on.

Comment: @DiegoNavarro except that's not true, I benchmarked both the `isalnum()` and regex versions, and the regex one is 50-75% faster

Comment: Tried this in Python3 - it accepts unicode chars so it's useless to me. Try string = "B223323\§§§$3\u445454" as an example. The result? 'B2233233䑔54'

Comment: Additionally: "For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent."! Thus the regex alternative is strictly better!

Comment: This does not preserve the white spaces between the words so not suitable for NLP

Answer (score 398):

Here is a regex to match a string of characters that are not a letters or numbers:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Here is the Python command to do a regex substitution:

```
re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', mystring)
```

Comment: this also removes the spaces between words, "great place" -> "greatplace". How to avoid it?

Comment: @Reihan_amn Simply add a space to the regex, so it becomes: `[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+`

Comment: @andy-white can you please add the space to the regex in the answer? Space is not a special character...

Comment: I guess this doesn't work with modified character in other languages, like **á**, **ö**, **ñ**, etc. Am I right? If so, how would it be the regex for it?

Comment: This doesn't work for Spanish, German, Danish and other languages.

Comment: For those worried about accented characters, there is a solution that will work in many cases at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18663728/210945

Comment: just add the special characters of that particular language. For example, to use for german text, re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9 ,.-_\'äöüÄÖÜß]+', '', sample_text) expression can be used.

Answer (score 80):

Shorter way  :

```
import re
cleanString = re.sub('\W+','', string )
```

If you want spaces between words and numbers substitute '' with ' '

Comment: Except that _ is in \w and is a special character in the context of this question.

Comment: Depends on the context - underscore is very useful for filenames and other identifiers, to the point that I don't treat it as a special character but rather a sanitised space.I generally use this method myself.

Comment: `r'\W+'` - slightly off topic (and very pedantic) but I suggest a habit that all regex patterns be [raw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13836171/673991)

Comment: This procedure does not treat underscore(_) as a special character.

Comment: A simple change to remove `_` as well: `r"[^A-Za-z]+"` instead of `r"\W+"`

Comment: You're welcome! Most of the points I have come from this answer :)

Answer (score 74):

### **TLDR**

I timed the provided answers.

```py
import re
re.sub('\W+','', string)
```

is typically **3x faster** than the next fastest provided top answer.

*Caution should be taken when using this option. Some special characters (e.g. **ø**) may not be striped using this method.*

---

After seeing this, I was interested in expanding on the provided answers by finding out which executes in the least amount of time, so I went through and checked some of the proposed answers with [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/timeit.html) against two of the example strings:

- `string1 = 'Special $#! characters   spaces 888323'`
- `string2 = 'how much for the maple syrup? $20.99? That s ridiculous!!!'`

#### Example 1

```py
'.join(e for e in string if e.isalnum())
```

- `string1` - Result: 10.7061979771
- `string2` - Result: 7.78372597694

#### Example 2

```py
import re
re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', string)
```

- `string1` - Result: 7.10785102844
- `string2` - Result: 4.12814903259

#### Example 3

```py
import re
re.sub('\W+','', string)
```

- `string1` - Result: 3.11899876595
- `string2` - Result: 2.78014397621

The above results are a product of the lowest returned result from an average of: `repeat(3, 2000000)`

**Example 3** can be 3x faster than **Example 1**.

Comment: @kkurian If you read the beginning of my answer, this is merely a comparison of the previously proposed solutions above.  You might want to comment on the originating answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/25183802/2560922

Comment: Oh, I see where you're going with this. Done!

Comment: Must consider Example 3, when dealing with large corpus.

Comment: Valid! Thanks for noting.

Comment: can you compare my answer `''.join([*filter(str.isalnum, string)])`

Comment: Third solution didn't remove the "ø" but the second one did remove it.

Comment: @TanmeyRawal Have you tried: re.sub('\W+','', string) ? It does remove space.

Comment: ```re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', string)``` is the most efficient and faster than the other solutions.

Comment: Solution 3 is still faster ‍♂️ based on timeit.

Answer (score 33):

#### Python 2.*

I think just `filter(str.isalnum, string)` works

```
In [20]: filter(str.isalnum, 'string with special chars like !,#$% etcs.')
Out[20]: 'stringwithspecialcharslikeetcs'
```

#### Python 3.*

In Python3, `filter( )` function would return an itertable object (instead of string unlike in above). One has to join back to get a string from itertable:

```
''.join(filter(str.isalnum, string))
```

or to pass `list` in join use ([not sure but can be fast a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/1673391))

```
''.join([*filter(str.isalnum, string)])
```

note: unpacking in `[*args]` valid from [Python >= 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33973612/1673391)

Comment: @Alexey  correct, In python3 `map`, `filter`, and `reduce`  returns itertable object instead. Still in Python3+ I will prefer  `''.join(filter(str.isalnum, string))`  (or  to pass list in join use `''.join([*filter(str.isalnum, string)])`)  over accepted answer.

Comment: I'm not certain `''.join(filter(str.isalnum, string))` is an improvement on `filter(str.isalnum, string)`, at least to read.  Is this really the Pythreenic (yeah, you can use that) way to do this?

Comment: @TheProletariat The point is *just `filter(str.isalnum, string)`* do not return string in Python3 as `filter( )` in Python-3 returns iterator rather than argument type unlike Python-2.+

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, I think you should update your answer to include both your Python2 and Python3 recommendations.

Answer (score 27):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

strs = "how much for the maple syrup? $20.99? That's ricidulous!!!"
print strs
nstr = re.sub(r'[?|$|.|!]',r'',strs)
print nstr
nestr = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]',r'',nstr)
print nestr
```

you can add more special character and that will be replaced by '' means nothing i.e they will be removed.

Answer (score 20):

string.punctuation contains following characters:

> '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'

You can use translate and maketrans functions to map punctuations to empty values (replace)

```
import string

'This, is. A test!'.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```

Output:

```
'This is A test'
```

Answer (score 19):

Differently than everyone else did using regex, I would try to exclude every character that **is not** what I want, instead of enumerating explicitly what I don't want.

For example, if I want only characters from 'a to z' (upper and lower case) and numbers, I would exclude everything else:

```
import re
s = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]","",s)
```

This means "substitute every character that is not a number, or a character in the range 'a to z' or 'A to Z' with an empty string".

In fact, if you insert the special character `^` at the first place of your regex, you will get the negation.

Extra tip: if you also need to **lowercase** the result, you can make the regex even faster and easier, as long as you won't find any uppercase now.

```
import re
s = re.sub(r"[^a-z0-9]","",s.lower())
```

Answer (score 15):

```
s = re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,]", "", s)
```

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you want to use a regex and you want/need Unicode-cognisant 2.x code that is 2to3-ready:

```
>>> import re
>>> rx = re.compile(u'[\W_]+', re.UNICODE)
>>> data = u''.join(unichr(i) for i in range(256))
>>> rx.sub(u'', data)
u'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\xaa\xb2 [snip] \xfe\xff'
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

The most generic approach is using the 'categories' of the unicodedata table which classifies every single character. E.g. the following code filters only printable characters based on their category:

```
import unicodedata
# strip of crap characters (based on the Unicode database
# categorization:
# http://www.sql-und-xml.de/unicode-database/#kategorien

PRINTABLE = set(('Lu', 'Ll', 'Nd', 'Zs'))

def filter_non_printable(s):
    result = []
    ws_last = False
    for c in s:
        c = unicodedata.category(c) in PRINTABLE and c or u'#'
        result.append(c)
    return u''.join(result).replace(u'#', u' ')
```

Look at the given URL above for all related categories. You also can of course filter
by the punctuation categories.

Comment: What's with the `$` at the end of each line?

Comment: If it's copy & paste issue, should you fix it then?

Answer (score 5):

For other languages like German, Spanish, Danish, French etc that contain special characters (like German "Umlaute" as `ü`, `ä`, `ö`) simply add these to the regex search string:

Example for German:

```
re.sub('[^A-ZÜÖÄa-z0-9]+', '', mystring)
```

Answer (score 5):

This will remove all special characters, punctuation, and spaces from a string and only have numbers and letters.

```
import re

sample_str = "Hel&&lo %% Wo$#rl@d"

# using isalnum()
print("".join(k for k in sample_str if k.isalnum()))


# using regex
op2 = re.sub("[^A-Za-z]", "", sample_str)
print(f"op2 = ", op2)


special_char_list = ["$", "@", "#", "&", "%"]

# using list comprehension
op1 = "".join([k for k in sample_str if k not in special_char_list])
print(f"op1 = ", op1)


# using lambda function
op3 = "".join(filter(lambda x: x not in special_char_list, sample_str))
print(f"op3 = ", op3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use translate:

```
import string

def clean(instr):
    return instr.translate(None, string.punctuation + ' ')
```

Caveat: Only works on ascii strings.

Comment: Version difference? I get `TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)` with py3.4

Comment: It is only working with Python2.7. See [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60725180/4820605) answer for using `translate` with Python3.

Answer (score 3):

This will remove all non-alphanumeric characters except spaces.

```
string = "Special $#! characters   spaces 888323"
''.join(e for e in string if (e.isalnum() or e.isspace()))
```

> Special  characters   spaces 888323

Comment: It will not remove double spacings

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
my_string = """Strings are amongst the most popular data types in Python. We can create the strings by enclosing characters in quotes. Python treats single quotes the
```

same as double quotes."""

```
# if we need to count the word python that ends with or without ',' or '.' at end

count = 0
for i in text:
    if i.endswith("."):
        text[count] = re.sub("^([a-z]+)(.)?$", r"\1", i)
    count += 1
print("The count of Python : ", text.count("python"))
```

Answer (score 0):

After 10 Years, below I wrote there is the best solution.
You can remove/clean all special characters, punctuation, ASCII characters and spaces from the string.

```
from clean_text import clean

string = 'Special $#! characters   spaces 888323'
new = clean(string,lower=False,no_currency_symbols=True, no_punct = True,replace_with_currency_symbol='')
print(new)
Output ==> 'Special characters spaces 888323'
you can replace space if you want.
update = new.replace(' ','')
print(update)
Output ==> 'Specialcharactersspaces888323'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function regexFuntion(st) {
  const regx = /[^\w\s]/gi; // allow : [a-zA-Z0-9, space]
  st = st.replace(regx, ''); // remove all data without [a-zA-Z0-9, space]
  st = st.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '); // remove multiple space

  return st;
}

console.log(regexFuntion('$Hello; # -world--78asdf+-===asdflkj******lkjasdfj67;'));
// Output: Hello world78asdfasdflkjlkjasdfj67
```

Answer (score -4):

```
import re
abc = "askhnl#$%askdjalsdk"
ddd = abc.replace("#$%","")
print (ddd)
```

and you shall see your result as

'askhnlaskdjalsdk

Comment: wait.... you imported `re` but never used it. Your `replace` criteria only works for this specific string. What if your string is `abc = "askhnl#$%!askdjalsdk"`? I don't think will work on anything other than the `#$%` pattern. Might wanna tweak it