# Regex Confusion Literal vs Nonliteral

Tags: python, regex

I understand the concept of backslashes and their use in escape sequences, but

#### Why do these produce the same results?

```
import re

print 'Test 1'

for i in re.findall("\n", "This\nis\na\ntest."):
    print 'Newline'

print 'Test 2'

for i in re.findall(r"\n", "This\nis\na\ntest."):
    print 'Newline'
```

Try the code [here](http://repl.it/bsa/1) in an online Python compiler.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you are asking the regex engine to search for a newline character. Python converts the `\n` to a newline character and passes it to `re.findall`.

In tthe second case, you are asking the regex engine to search for `\n`. Python passes `\n` to `re.findall`. The regex engine knows that `\n` means newline.

So you get the same result; the unescaping of the `\n` merely happens at a different stage of the process.

Comment: So the regex interprets the pattern as it pleases? Even if you explicitly supply a different pattern.

Comment: It doesn't interpret it "as it pleases," it interprets it as it is documented to do. You have supplied two different patterns, but they match the same character, so you get the same result.

Comment: So how to you distinguish if you want to search for a literal backslash with an n?

Comment: Escape the backslash, e.g. `r"\\n"`

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of the raw string modifier?

Comment: No. Without the raw string modifier you'd need to write `"\\\\n"`.

Comment: To elaborate further, you have to get the backslash through *two* layers of unescaping. Python unescapes the string (unless you have `r` in front of it), and then the regex engine *also* does it. So it takes four backslashes in a normal Python string literal to search for one backslash using a regex.