# Python - escaping || when splitting string with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm trying to split a string like `a && b || c && d || e` on both `&&` and `||` using re.split. I know you can have multiple delimiters by doing `re.split("a | b")`, however I don't know how to achieve this: `re.split("&& | ||")`. I attempted to escape the pipes by using `re.split("&& | \\|\\|")` however this doesn't work.

How do I properly escape this?

Comment: Be warned that you may be mistaken in your regex comprehension. `re.split("a | b")` will split on `a(space)` and `(space)b`. Your own attempt also includes these spaces (which happen to be in your input, and so they will be discarded).

Comment: What do you want as output?

Answer (score 5):

You need to *escape* the `|` since it has a special meaning:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "a && b || c && d || e"
>>> re.split(r"&&|\|\|", s)
['a ', ' b ', ' c ', ' d ', ' e']
```

And, to also handle the spaces around the delimiters:

```
>>> re.split(r"\s(?:&&|\|\|)\s", s)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

where `\s` matches a space character, `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups).

Comment: Is it important to mark the parenthesized expression as non-capturing?

Comment: @RadLexus yeah, otherwise the delimiters would also be present in the resulting list. Thanks.

Comment: Just ran over to my desktop to check :) Nice caveat! Just a quick follow up question: on my Python 2.7  also works without the `r` prefix: `re.split(" *&& *| *\|\| *", s)` *and* also with doubled backslashes! Basically, OPs original attempt works! (With the associated space problem I mentioned in a comment.) Any reason for that?

Comment: @RadLexus that's the "magic" of the raw string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it.

Answer (score 1):

*str.translate* might do the job if you want to split into individual elements:

```
s = "a && b || c && d || e"

print(s.translate(None,"&|").split())
```

Which would give you:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Or replace the double || with && and then split:

```
s = "a && b || c && d || e"

print(s.replace(" || "," && ").split(" && "))
```

Or if you want to keep the spacing, just `s.replace("||","&&").split("&&")`, whatever you want you can use some variation of the above or combine with *str.strip*.

Answer (score 0):

Did this regex respond to your need ?

```
import re
r = re.compile("(?:&&|\|\|)")
r.split("a && b || c && d || e")
```

result :

```
['a ', ' b ', ' c ', ' d ', ' e']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data = "a && b || c && d || e"
import re
spl = re.split("(?:\|\||&&)",data)
print spl
```

or else use find all with regex negation

```
import re
data = "a && b || c && d || e"
data2 = re.findall("[^&|]{2}",data)
print data2
```