# Add space before bracket if there is any character

Tags: python, regex

How can I add space before open bracket `(` if there is any character and don't add space if there is a space?

I tried with this expression:

```
re.sub("\[^}]*\(", ' $1', line)
```

But it's not working.

How can I check if there is any character before open bracket and if there is no space, add space?

Comment: In Python, use `\1` style backreferences with a raw string literal. And you have no capture groups, so you cannot use `\1` here at all.

Comment: `line = re.sub(r'(?<!\s|^)\(', ' (', line)`

Comment: @anubhava: It also depends whether a space should be inserted if `(` is at the string start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
(\S)\(
```

And replace with `r'\1 ('`. The `(\S)` will capture into Group 1 any character that is not a whitespace. Since it is a consuming subpattern, no `(` at the string start will get matched (there must be a character before a `(`).

The backreferences are defined with a backslash in Python (or with `\g<n>` syntax to make them unambiguous).

Note that to also match a `(` at the beginning of a string (to add a space before the first `(` in a string), use `r'(?<!\s)\('` regex (with a non-consuming subpattern - a negative lookbehind `(?<!\s)` that makes sure there is no whitespace character before a `(`):

```
re.sub(r"(?<!\s)\(", r' (', "(some text)") # => " (some text)"
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kuZ1AW):

```
import re
print(re.sub(r"(\S)\(", r'\1 (', "(some text)"))      # => (some text)
print(re.sub(r"(\S)\(", r'\1 (', "Text(some text)"))  # => Text (some text)
print(re.sub(r"(?<!\s)\(", r' (', "(some text)"))     # =>  (some text)
```

Please note the use of raw string literals to declare both the regex and the regex replacement (this helps avoid many unexpected issues). See [*What exactly is a “raw string regex” and how can you use it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

Try sub this:

```
(\w)\(
```

With this:

```
\1 (
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZ7fE3/1)