# Python regex substitute ignoring escape characters

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
import os

MARKER = 'hello'
readFileData = "['\\n', '\\r', '\\0'];\nvar MONTH_TO_NUM = { jan: 0, feb: 1, mar: 2 };\n"
outFileBuffer ='updated file\nhello\n'

outFileBuffer = re.sub(MARKER, (readFileData + MARKER), outFileBuffer)

# output of re.sub doesn't preserve double slash \\
# outFileBuffer = "updated file\n['\n', '\r', '\x00'];\nvar MONTH_TO_NUM = { jan: 0, feb: 1, mar: 2 };\nhello\n"

destination = os.getcwd() + "test.txt"
with open(destination, "w") as f:
  f.write(outFileBuffer)
```

**input.txt**

```
var TERMINATORS = ['\n', '\r', '\0'];
var MONTH_TO_NUM = { jan: 0, feb: 1, mar: 2 };
```

Contents of **input.txt** are stored in **readFileData** variable after reading.

As soon as **re.sub** fn is used double forward slash are converted to single slash. Refer **outFileBuffer** comment.

When the buffer is written back to disk `var TERMINATORS = ['\n', '\r', '\0'];` seems to messed up, because outFileBuffer is not escaped properly.

How can escaped string be preserved while using re.sub method.

Comment: Right, you need `re.sub(MARKER, readFileData + MARKER, outFileBuffer.replace('\\', '\\\\'))`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56524477/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. but it works with `readFileData  = readFileData.replace('\\', '\\\\')`

Comment: The point is that all backslashes in the dynamic string replacement patterns must be doubled in order to be literal backslashes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yup `re.sub(MARKER, (readFileData + MARKER).replace('\\', '\\\\'), outFileBuffer).replace('\\', '\\\\')`