# Avoid the replacement pattern to be interpreted as regex with re.sub

Tags: python, regex, python-re

In the following `content`, I want to replace what is inside `--START--` / `--END--` by a string `filelist` containing both:

- `\` character
- newlines (`\n`)

This code nearly works:

```
import re

content = """A
--START--
tobereplaced
--END--
C"""

filelist = """c:\\test\\l1.txt
c:\\test\\l2.txt"""

print(re.sub(r'(--START--\n).*?(\n--END--)', r'\1' + re.escape(filelist) + r'\2', 
                  content, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL))
```

but:

- without `re.escape(...)`, it fails because of the `\\l`. One solution might be to hack every `\` as `'\\\\'` or `r'\\'`, but it's not really elegant (in my real code, `filelist` is read from a file produced by another tool)
- with `re.escape(...)`, then in the output, every newline has a trailing `\` and every `.` becomes `\.` which I don't want:

  ```
  A
  --START--
  c:\test\l1\.txt\
  c:\test\l2\.txt
  --END--
  C
  ```

**How to fix this? and how `re.sub(..., r'\1' + repl + r'\2', ...)` treat `repl` as a normal string and no regex pattern?**

Desired output:

```
A
--START--
c:\test\l1.txt
c:\test\l2.txt
--END--
C
```

Comment: You need to replace `r'\1' + re.escape(filelist) + r'\2'` with `r'\1' + filelist.replace('\\', '\\\\') + r'\2'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There could also be some other characters that risk to be interpreted as a regex pattern in `filelist`, how to avoid this?

Comment: No, the only one is a ``\``.

Comment: How to be sure @WiktorStribiżew? `filelist` can contain URLs with `&`, `?`, `:`, `/`, and many more characters that could be understood as regex special char, don't you think so?

Comment: Very well, let them contain anything. The only special character in a substitution pattern is a backslash. Only the backslash must be doubled. And you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I upvoted your answer on the duplicate too, it was useful! PS: you could add your last comment to your answer in the duplicate question *"The only special character in a substitution pattern is a backslash. Only the backslash must be doubled. And you are good to go.`*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes this TL;DR would help to get the general idea for future readers :)