# Get all text between a specified string with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How can I get a string between 2 specified strings in Python3 using regex?

```
b'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.11\r\n'
```

desired output:

```
>>> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.11
```

```
# ipsort.py
import re

f = open("ssh.txt", "r")

line = f.readline()

for line in f:
    version = re.search(r"b'(.*?)\r\n'", line)
    new_file = open("ssh_versions.txt", "a")
    new_file.write(version)
    new_file.close()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ipsort.py", line 11, in <module>
    new_file.write(version)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
```

Comment: What are the "two specified strings"?

Comment: In general, use `string1(.*?)string2` and then get capture group 1.

Comment: Sorry my bad... b' and \r\n

Comment: Edit the question to make it clearer, don't use comments.

Comment: I was having problems with the backslash being an escape character

Comment: That's why you should always use a raw string when creating a regexp.

Comment: I'm reasonably new to Python and very new to regular expressions, what exactly do you mean by always use a raw string?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it

Comment: yes I'm still stuck. Referring to other resources is what I've been doing for hours but I still cant do it, I keep getting errors. A straight answer with a code example would be appreciated.

Comment: The regexp should be: `r"b'(.*?)\r\n'"`

Comment: Nope... that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double the `\` in the regexp, because otherwise it's matching CR and LF characters rather than literal `\r` and `\n`.

You also need to use `version.group(1)` to get the string that the capture group matched.

```
version = re.search(r"b'(.*?)\\r\\n'", line)
if version:
    with open("ssh_versions.txt", "a") as new_file:
        new_file.write(version.group(1))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. It was seriously frustrating. Regular expressions are complicated, its like learning a new language.