# New line symbols are not detected by regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I import data from csv and read it with pandas:

```
train = pd.read_csv('yelp_review_full_csv/train.csv',
                    header=None,
                    names=['Class', 'Review'])

reviews = train['Review']
```

and willing to get rid of new line symbols - \n using regex:

```
print(reviews[3])
rex = re.sub("\\n+", " ", reviews[3])
print(rex)
```

which gives me an output:

```
... much.  \n\nI think ...
... much.  \n\nI think ...
```

If I copy the output and check it with regex, then I have a desired result. I guess there should be something with csv reading, any recommendations?

Comment: What is `reviews` and how does it relate to `train`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the erroneous output. What yields print(reviews[3])?

Comment: Why are you escaping the backslash? Doesn't `rex = re.sub(r"\n+", " ", reviews[3])` work for you?

Comment: @Toto It looks like his text has literal `\n` in it, not newline characters.

Comment: @Barmar,  sorry for that, I've edited the code

Comment: @Ronald, I've edited the code. fyi reviews[3] = "Got a letter in the mail last week that said Dr. Goldberg is moving to Arizona to take a new position there in June.  He will be missed very much.  \n\nI think finding a new doctor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text contains literal `\n` in it, not newlines.

The regexp `\n` matches a newline, not literal `\n`. To match `\n` you need to use the regexp `\\n`. Escaping the backslash just allows the backslash to be passed to the regexp parser. You need to double-escape it so that the regexp will match `\n`, or use a raw string.

```
rex = re.sub(r"(\\n)+, " ", reviews[3])
```

See [What exactly is a "raw string regex" and how can you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it)