# How to write a python regex to extract user name used in su command?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of various `su` commands.  All the commands use the full path to the `su` command.
And the commands may or may not have a username and may or may not have the `-` option.

Also there maybe options and arguments after the username like `/usr/bin/su aa*` or    `/bin/su - squid *` or `/bin/su - mapr -c "/usr/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /user/*"`.

Here is what I have tried and I didn't get very far before I ran into trouble.

```
for c in su_commands.all()[0:10]:
   ...:     print(c.name)
   ...:     m = re.search('/su\s*[-]\s*(\S*)', c.name).group(1)
   ...:     print(m)
   ...:     
//bin/su - audituser.gen
audituser.gen
//usr/bin/su - hradm
hradm
/apps/su - capital
capital
/apps/su - cscdm
cscdm
/apps/su - invadm
invadm
/bib/su sapbridg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/sfo_rcecala/sfo_rcecala/env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-39-788d11c0e2c2>", line 3, in <module>
    m = re.search('/su\s*[-]\s*(\S*)', c.name).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I thought that have `[-]` in my regex would make the `-` optional.

---

Thanks Barmar.  I have updated my regex and now I am getting further.

```
for c in su_commands.all()[0:10]:
   ...:     print(c.name)
   ...:     m = re.search('/su\s*\-?\s*(\S*)', c.name).group(1)
   ...:     print(m)
   ...:     
//bin/su - audituser.gen
audituser.gen
//usr/bin/su - hradm
hradm
/apps/su - capital
capital
/apps/su - cscdm
cscdm
/apps/su - invadm
invadm
/bib/su sapbridg
sapbridg
/bin//su - hdpapjpa
hdpapjpa
/bin/su  oabifstg

/bin/su  xxcconx
xxcconx
/bin/su  xxswaadm
xxswaadm
```

But as you can see I missed the user `oabifstg`.

Comment: Why do you think `[-]` makes it optional? The syntax to make something optional is to put `?` after it.

Comment: @RedCricket I deleted my comment before you replied - the manual page for `su` says `su [options] [username]` but then I saw that options after the username in fact work and are included in your strings (I didn't read the question carefully enough).

Comment: Are there any examples where the commands actually use options (other than just the `-`) *before* the username? That could complicate things.

Comment: @alaniwi there are.  like `/bin/su -l puppetadmin`

Comment: @RedCricket That's going to be fun then, especially considering that some options take arguments and others don't. I wondered about splitting it up into a list and then using `argparse` just as you would if your code was actually implementing `su`... but even that will be complicated because these are shell commands and spaces inside quotes would need protecting from splitting somehow. Don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to make something optional is to put `?` after it. Square brackets are for specifying a character set, e.g. `[abc]` matches either `a`, `b`, or `c`.

Try this.

```py
m = re.search(r'/su\s+(?:-\s+)?(\S*)', c.name).group(1)
```

At least one space is required after `su`, then `-` followed by spaces is an optional group.

If you want to allow arbitrary options before the username, use a repeating group that matches `-` followed by zero or more non-space characters.

```py
m = re.search(r'/su\s+(?:-\S*\s+)*(\S*)', c.name).group(1)
```

I also used a raw string so that all the escape sequences would be processed by the `re` module. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it) for more details.

Comment: That regex works great.  But I just realized that I have command in the list that look like this: `/bin/su -l mongod` How can I work the in the extra `l`?

Comment: I've updated the answer to allow any number of options before the username.