# return only chars from the string in python

Tags: python-3.x, string

I am looking to extract only chars from the given string. but my query is doing exactly opposite

```
s= "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"

newS = ''.join(re.findall("[^a-zA-Z]*", s))
print(newS) // my o/p:  ,  ,  :
```

expected o/p string is:

```
"A man a plan a canal Panama"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression is inverting the match - that's what the caret symbol (`^`) does inside square brackets (negated character class). You first need to remove that.

Next, you should be matching a sequence of one or more characters (`+`) rather than zero or more characters (`*`) -- using `*` will match the empty string, which you don't want in this case.

Finally your `join` should join with a space to get the intended output, rather than an empty string -- which won't retain the spaces between the words.

```
newS = ' '.join(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', s))
```

Though not essential in this case, its advised to use raw strings for regular expressions (`r`). More in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it) post.

Full working code:

```
import re

s = 'A man, a plan, a canal: Panama'

newS = ' '.join(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', s))

print(newS)
```