# Python regex for fixed character length

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am new to regex am trying to create a simple regex. I have gotten below so far which works for the format I'm trying to test against.

```
import re
pattern = '^\+61-' #to ensure that the given string starts with +61
x = re.search(pattern, '+61-457999999')
print(x)
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='+61-'>
```

What I'd like to do next is to add the character count check. So I tried to add `{}` to the end of my pattern. But this doesn't seem to work. I tried various combinations:

E.g.  `'^\+61-{1}'` - seems to look for 1 number of occurrence of `'+61-'` at the beginning.

What would be an appropriate addition to the regex so:

1. The starting characters are always `'+61-4'`
2. The length of the given input is always 13

This sounds like a simple question but I was unable to find an exact matching answer for Python and the scenario described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution would be to match the length with a lookahead: `(?=^.{13}$)`. Full example:

```
>>> bool(re.search(r"(?=^.{13}$)^\+61-", '+61-457999999'))
True
>>> bool(re.search(r"(?=^.{13}$)^\+61-", '+62-457999999'))
False
>>> bool(re.search(r"(?=^.{13}$)^\+61-", '+61-4579999999'))
False
>>> bool(re.search(r"(?=^.{13}$)^\+61-", '+61-45799999'))
False
```

You could also be more precise and match the format, assuming digits after the `-`:

```
>>> bool(re.fullmatch(r"\+61-\d{9}", '+61-457999999'))
True
>>> bool(re.fullmatch(r"\+61-\d{9}", '+62-457999999'))
False
>>> bool(re.fullmatch(r"\+61-\d{9}", '+61-4579999999'))
False
>>> bool(re.fullmatch(r"\+61-\d{9}", '+61-45799999'))
False
```

Or use `.{9}` if you want to match anything for the remaining 9 characters after the starting substring.

The reason `'^\+61-{1}'` doesn't work is it's specifying 1 occurrence of the preceding character `-`. `{1}` is always implicit after every character so that's no different than `'^\+61-'`.

As an aside, always use [raw strings `r""` for regex patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it) in Python.

As another aside, you're in Python so it's easy to check the string's length with `len`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Great descriptions on the comments. And yes I've been using `len` separately and was wondering if it would be better to do it all in one regex. Thanks again for the detailed info. Appreciate it.