# Disection of re 're.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z][\w_]{2,23}[^_]$")'

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm new to python programming and doing some challenges to improve my coding; I encounter the following regular expression: `(r"^[a-zA-Z][\w_]{2,23}[^_]$").`

Doing some research, I understand this:

`r"` = The expression is a raw string (not sure what this mean entirely)

`^[a-zA-Z]` = This tells me that the string must start with a letter

`[\w_]{2,23}` = the body of the string from `val[2]` to `val[23]` must be alphanumeric

`[^_]$` = the end must be an underscore

If my research is correct, I don't understand why the **`[\w_]` contains an underscore on it**. I thought for alphanumerics must be only `[\w].`

If I'm wrong, help me to clarify it.

Comment: correction  ->`[\w_]{2,23}` = there must next be an alphanumeric string with a length anywhere between 2 and 23.

Comment: `[\w_]` = alphanumeric *or* underscore; square brackets define a character set that matches anything listed within it.  `[^_]` = anything *except* an underscore; a caret as the first character of a set negates it.

Comment: @jasonharper `\w` doesn't mean "alphanumeric". Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#index-32).

Comment: @Evergreen Is right; I needed correction regarding my research. My apologies.

Comment: Are you looking for confirmation about *all* of those points? If so, that's too broad for a Stack Overflow question; instead please ask only one *specific* question at a time, but by all means provide all the details for context. Have you read the docs for the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)? It explains all of the syntax and why to use raw strings. Also if you want a raw string demo, [see the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). For more tips, see [ask]. [My previous comment to this effect was deleted and I have no idea why.]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it for why a raw string is used.

Answer (score -1):

`\` is an escape character
`\w` in regex is considered one character because of the escape character
it means:

> any 'word like' (ascii) character `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`\

when you do [\w_], this is any `word like character` OR an `underscore`. The underscore is not needed as it is included in `\w`.

Comment: An underscore **is** a word character. Read the docs: [`\w`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#index-32)

Comment: this is a community wiki if you wanted to change it...

Comment: I'd post my own answer if I wanted to, cause this one doesn't address all of OP's confusions, among other problems. But then, the question itself is too broad.