# Python notebook - Importing data file with delimiter with two characters causes an error

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-sql-database

**Question**: We are encountering the following error when loading a data file - that has two characters delimiter - to an `Azure SQL Db`. What we may be doing wrong and how can the issue be resolved?

Using a `Python` notebook in [Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/what-is-azure-databricks#:%7E:text=Azure%20Databricks%20is%20a%20data,Microsoft%20Azure%20cloud%20services%20platform.&text=For%20a%20big%20data%20pipeline,Event%20Hub%2C%20or%20IoT%20Hub.), we are trying to load a data file into [Azure SQL Db](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-database-paas-overview). The delimiter in the data file has two characters `~*`. On the following code we get the errors shown below:

> pandas dataframe low memory not supported with the 'python' engine

**Code**:

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/MyDataFile.txt', sep='~*', engine='python', low_memory=False, quotechar='"', header='infer' , encoding='cp1252')
.............
.............
```

**Remarks**: If we remove the `low_memory` option, we get the following error. Although with other data files that are even larger than this file but have delimiter with a single character, we don't get the following error.

> ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
> Error while obtaining a new communication channel
> ConnectException error: This is often caused by an OOM error that causes the connection to the Python REPL to be closed. Check your query's memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`Pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> In addition, separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+' will be interpreted as regular expressions and will also force the use of the Python parsing engine.

Since it's being interpreted as a regular expression, and `*` has special meaning in regexp, you need to escape it. Use `sep=r'~\*'`

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). To the point and well explained response (my upvote). I assume `r` is a typo in `sep=r'~\*'`. If not please let me know what that's for. Also, for the benefit of other users, you may want to provide a link to the document you've referred.

Comment: No, it's not a typo. That's a raw string literal, needed because of the backaslash in the regexp. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it

Comment: I have a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72209325/1232087) in case you have time for a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your File ist too large and the dataframe does not fit in memory. Can you try to split the Processing Up? I.e. read 1000 Limes, make a dataframe from that, Push to SQL, Thema read next 1000 lines etc?

nrows and skiprows passed to read_csv can be used for this.

Maybe a workaround: preprocess the file with `sed s/-*/;/g`, then you can use the c engine with lower memory footprint.