# Apache Spark data file with multi characters delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, databricks

I have a "CSV" file that uses a multi-character delimiter, so the data looks something like

```
field1^|^,^|^field2^|^,^|^field3^|^,^|^field4
```

Following code in a notebook inside `Databricks` throws the error (shown below) on the second line where it tries to write dataframe `df` to a destination table:

```
df = spark.read.csv(".../Test/MyFile.csv", sep="^|^,^|^", header="true", inferSchema="true")
df.write.(.....)
```

Error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Spark Dataframe and SQL Server table have differing numbers of columns

Both the csv files and the database tables have exact same column names and have exact number of columns. The error seems to indicate that the delimiter `^|^,^|^` is not being recognized. Is there a way to parse this data file with this ^|^,^|^ delimiter?

**UPDATE**: My bad, I forgot to include `sep` attribute in the `spark.read.csv(...)` call above. I have added that attribute now, and its value `^|^,^|^`. But the error is still the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349762/8279585 -- refer this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 things on databricks

1. Give the option for spark to read with this delimiter like `spark.read.option("delimiter", "^|^,^|^").csv(".../Test/MyFile.csv", header = "true", inferSchema = "true")`   - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349762)
2. Have python or shell script to handle that before the file gets loaded by Spark! as follow. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35130508)

```python
with open(".../Test/MyFile.csv") as f:
    newText = f.read().replace('^|^,^|^', '|')
```

Also, you can try df.show() to make sure your dataframe columns are read properly.

Comment: I already have that `sep` attribute used in the call to `spark.read.csv(...)`. It was my fault, I had forgotten to add it to the code. I just added it now and added an **UPDATE** section. But the error is still there. It's a `UTF-16 LE BOM` file, I wonder if it has anything to do with the error.

Comment: You may try adding an option `.option("encoding", "UTF-16")`. If you are lucky, it will work! It seems this is an [unresolved SPARK issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32965).