# Python lint issue : invalid escape sequence '\/'

Tags: python, lint

This is my python code line which is giving me  **invalid escape sequence '/'** lint issue.

```
pattern = 'gs:\/\/([a-z0-9-]+)\/(.+)$'  # for regex matching
```

It is giving me out that error for all the backslash I used here .
any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: You don't need to escape `/` in Python regular expressions.

Comment: You should be using a raw string for a regular expression, so the backslashes will be passed through transparently to the regexp engine.

Comment: @Barmar so how would the above pattern will look for regex matching?

Comment: @quicksilver, what do you mean by that question? `pattern = 'gs://([a-z0-9-]+)/(.+)$'` is enough on its own; it doesn't need anything else to "look for regex matching". The answer advising use of a raw string is good for the future so you can use backslashes in later versions of your regex, but your current regex doesn't strictly need it; all you need to do is take out the unnecessary backslashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two issues here:

1. Since this is not a raw string, the backslashes are string escapes, not regexp escapes. Since `\/` is not a valid string escape sequence, you get that warning. Use a raw string so that the backslashes will be ignored by the string parser and passed to the regexp engine. See [What exactly is a "raw string regex" and how can you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it)
2. In some languages `/` is part of the regular expression syntax (it's the delimiter around the regexp), so they need to be escaped. But Python doesn't use `/` this way, so there's no need to escape them in the first place.

Use this:

```
pattern = r'gs://([a-z0-9-]+)/(.+)$'  # for regex matching
```