# Regex to match string and special characters

Tags: python, regex, string

I am new to regex and I want to know how to generate a pattern with letters including special characters and Capital letters from 3 letters up.

Suppose I have a string like this:

```
my_string = 'Syrians/NORP, Turkish/NORP, Turkish/NORP, Turkish/NORP, the last 2 , 3 years/DATE, Turkey/LOC'
```

What I have tried:

```
my_new_string = re.findall('[\w+\,]+/[A-Z]{4}', my_string)
#result
['Syrians/NORP', 'Turkish/NORP', 'Turkish/NORP', 'Turkish/NORP', 'years/DATE']
```

Expected result:

```
['Syrians/NORP', 'Turkish/NORP', 'Turkish/NORP', 'Turkish/NORP', 'the last 2 , 3 years/DATE', 'Turkey/LOC']
```

I also struggled with the pattern of capital letters from 3 or up.

Can you propose a good solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: handle the space, and make that last group optional

Comment: Add `\s` to `[\w+,]`. BTW, there's no need to escape `,`.

Comment: Remember to use a raw string for Python regular expressions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it

Comment: To match 3 up use `{3,}` instead of `{4}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w[\w, ]+/[A-Z]{3,4}', my_string)
['Syrians/NORP', 'Turkish/NORP', 'Turkish/NORP', 'Turkish/NORP', 'the last 2 , 3 years/DATE', 'Turkey/LOC']
```

just add space to your character class (where the '+' is not needed after `\w`), and range from 3 to 4 to match "LOC" (or whatever range you need). Start with an alphanum to avoid matching leading spaces (which also matches `_` btw but not a problem here)