# Removing words in a list from column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of various wines. I am trying to remove all punctuation, all words containing 4 or fewer characters, as well as the words flavors, aromas, finish, and drink from the string values contained in the 'description' column. My code does not appear to be working and I have also tried various permutations of this to no avail.

`remove_list = ['[^\w\s]', '[\b(\w{1,4})\b]', 'flavors', 'aromas', 'finish', 'drink']`

`df11['description'].str.replace('|'.join(remove_list), '', regex=True)`

Comment: do you have some sample data and what is your expected output? you can also read ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: This look right.. For starters I'd test out the individual replace elements and see how that acts

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `r` to avoid escape characters in your regex pattern. [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it#:%7E:text=The%20solution%20is%20to%20use,character%20string%20containing%20a%20newline.)

try:

```py
remove_list = [r'[^\w\s]', r'\b\w{1,3}\b', 'flavors', 'aromas', 'finish', 'drink']
```

to replicate everything:

```
import pandas as pd
# create data
data = {'description': ["I don't like this wine. And flavors are really bad."]}
df11 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df11)

remove_list = [r'[^\w\s]', r'\b\w{1,3}\b', 'flavors', 'aromas', 'finish', 'drink']

df11['description'].replace('|'.join(remove_list), '', regex=True)
```

output is:

[image]

Comment: This could use more explanation as to _why_ you think this should work.

Comment: Sure, let me paste my replication code when I tested this. I think OP forgot to make it r string to avoid escape characters. But the question definitely should be improved with input and desired output and what are the problems.