# strange python regex: not able to find match

Tags: python, regex

I am facing some strange python regex issue. The following two strings are supposedly to be exactly the same. But somehow they are not matching.

```
import re
print(" \\\"")
print(" "+chr(92)+chr(34)+"")
print(re.search(" \\\"", " "+chr(92)+chr(34)+""))
```

However, the following does match

```
import re
print("\\\"")
print(""+chr(92)+chr(34)+"")
print(re.search("\\\"", ""+chr(92)+chr(34)+""))
```

Any thought on what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is the backslash character has special meaning to a string in python. You can use a Python raw string created by prefixing a string literal with 'r' or 'R' where python raw string treats backslash `(\)` as a literal character.

```
import re
print(" \\\"")
print(" "+chr(92)+chr(34)+"")
print(re.search(r" \\\"", " "+chr(92)+chr(34)+""))
```

**Output:**

```
 \"
 \"
<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match=' \\"'>
```

In second example `print(re.search("\\\"", ""+chr(92)+chr(34)+""))` outputs:
`<re.Match object; span=(1, 2), match='"'>` where only the double quote is matched.

Need to escape the backslash or use a raw string. If use single-quotes around the regexp then the double-quote does not need to be escaped.

```
s = "" + chr(92) + chr(34) + ""
print(re.search("\\\\\"", s))
print(re.search(r"\\\"", s))
print(re.search(r'\\"', s))
```

**Output:**

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='\\"'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='\\"'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='\\"'>
```

For further details on raw string and backslash in Python, see answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12871066/543969).

Comment: why the second case passed though?

Comment: Notice the output of the match for second case `<re.Match object; span=(1, 2), match='"'>` which is only matching the single quote.

Comment: so when \ has nothing to escape, it just got thrown away?

Comment: if wanted to match \ as literal then would need `print(re.search("\\\\\"", ""+chr(92)+chr(34)+""))`