# Escaping matched strings before replacing in re.sub

Tags: python, python-re

I need to chain matching two user supplied patterns where in between matches I replace the captured matched content in the second pattern.

```
pattern 1 -> match data 1 -> replace captured matches in pattern 2 -> match data2
```

To do this safely, I need to escape the captured matches, so they don't interfere with second pattern.

For example:

```
def process(pattern1, pattern2, data1=r'A[1]', data2=r'B[1]'):
    result = re.sub(pattern1, pattern2, data1)
    return re.match(result, data2)
```

In this case, `process(r'A\[(\d+)]', r'B\[\1]')` will work, while `process(r'A(.+)', r'B\1')` will not, because the `result` will be `B[1]` and the `[]` will be treated as part of the regex. I don't think I can escape the `data1` first, because I don't know what pattern1 will be like.

To make it work, the captured match needs to be escaped first (after pattern1 has matched data1) before substituting in pattern2. This way, `result` is `B\[1]`, which can then match `B[1]` exactly.

Please note that both inputs to `process` are assumed to be valid expressions. For example, `process(r'[A-Z]+(.*)', r'\1_\2', 'A[1]', 'A_[1]')`.

I looked at using using a function in `re.sub` as the second parameter, but that is expected to return a single string, so I am not sure how to deal with the captured groups.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Just to make it clear, this is not a question about escaping per se, obviously `re.escape` can do it. The question how and where would you do the escaping in the sequence being mention in the original question.

EDIT2: The string that needs to be escaped lives in the captured match group. How would you escape that?

EDIT3: Added raw string for prettiness.

Comment: Don't forget to use raw strings when you're creating regular expressions in Python. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it

Comment: Use `re.escape()` to escape all special regexp characters in a string, so they'll be treated literally.

Comment: This is not about re.escape. This is about where/how would you escape the string, if the string is in the captured match group. However close the question, can you please don't close before reading carefully. Thank you!

Comment: I think you may need to use a function for the replacement, instead of a string, so you can use `re.escape(match.group(1))` when substituting. But I'm having trouble understanding the whole use. Can you show a specific example of the desired inputs and result?