# Bash: How to use sed to remove all characters except letters and numbers?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

First off, I'm still learning about regular expression, I have googled about this but still doesn't work.

How do I remove all characters except letters and numbers in a variable with `sed`? For example I have this text file:

```
MytextOnly !@#!text@@32423#@$text#%$#text%#t23432ext$32342%^-_+-=-_++_;:"'][}}{|\/
```

How do I show only letters and numbers?

Comment: Why specify that an answer must "use sed"? Why not ask for an answer that uses either bash or POSIX-standardized tools, and let folks give you the best tool for the job?

Comment: Because I didn't know that, please remember that I'm still learning

Comment: That's my point -- since you're still learning, it's best to ask questions in a general enough way that you leave them open to answers that might be outside the realm you initially expect. For instance, if you have `SomeShellVar='abc123def456'`, you can `echo "${SomeShellVar//[^[:alpha:]]/}"` (or `LettersOnly=${SomeShellVar//[^[:alpha:]]/}` if you don't want to `echo` the output) to remove anything that isn't a letter, completely internal to bash. Same thing with `[^[:alnum:]]` to leave only letters and numbers -- far faster than any external tool when you're working with shell variables.

Comment: ...granted, that approach is focused on variables, as opposed to files; for working on files, the answers you have now are good (though if you want to do file edits in-place in a way that works on all POSIX platforms, `ex` is another good tool to know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]\+//g' file
MytextOnlytext32423texttextt23432ext32342
```

`[^[:alnum:]]` property will find all non-alphanumerical characters.

---

**EDIT:** Based on comments below:

```
sed 's~[^[:alnum:]/]\+~~g' file
MytextOnlytext32423texttextt23432ext32342/
```

Comment: Thanks that works, can you explain what `\+` does ? and also what if I want to add forward slash as well, so it shows letters, numbers and forward slashes?

Comment: Because of `/g` global `\+` is not even necessary, I think.

Comment: Check my updated answer for allowing forward slash. @Tiago: Quantifier `+` is used for efficiency so that less # of replacements happen.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep`

```
grep -o '[[:alnum:]]' file
```

agree, no the perfect output, but everything is there

Using `tr`

```
$ tr -d -c '[:alnum:]' < file
MytextOnlytext32423texttextt23432ext32342
```

If you also want to keep forward slashes:

```
$ tr -d -c '[:alnum:]/' < file
MytextOnlytext32423texttextt23432ext32342/
```

For a python solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5843560/297323

Comment: what if I want to add forward slash as well, so it shows letters, numbers and forward slashes

Comment: then just add `\/` to the character class, the `-c` flag negates everything specified, saying delete everything not matched by the character class

Comment: For that python link, How do I keep spaces and forward slash? so it shows letters, numbers, spaces and forward slashes ?