# How to remove special characters from strings in python?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, special-characters, python-unicode

I have millions of strings scraped from web like:

```
s = 'WHAT\xe2\x80\x99S UP DOC?'
type(s) == str # returns True
```

Special characters like in the string above are inevitable when scraping from the web. How should one remove all such special characters to retain just clean text? I am thinking of regular expression like this based on my very limited experience with unicode characters:

```
\\x.*[0-9]
```

Comment: They are not special characters, that is a utf-8 encoded string, which when printed will output `WHAT’S UP DOC?`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843518/remove-all-special-characters-punctuation-and-spaces-from-string

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Thanks for correcting me. I meant the same thing.

Comment: So you want any non-ascii removed? i.e `print(s.decode("ascii",errors="ignore"))`

Comment: Works like butter. Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want to mention this solution or should I write it down in my answer?

Comment: @mousecoder, work away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special characters are not actually multiple characters long, that is just how they are represented so your regex isn't going to work. If you `print` you will see the actual unicode (utf-8) characters

```
>>> s = 'WHAT\xe2\x80\x99S UP DOC?'
>>> print(s)
WHATâS UP DOC?
>>> repr(s)
"'WHATâ\\x80\\x99S UP DOC?'"
```

If you want to print only the ascii characters you can check if the character is in `string.printable`

```
>>> import string
>>> ''.join(i for i in s if i in string.printable)
'WHATS UP DOC?'
```

Answer (score 2):

This thing worked for me as mentioned by Padriac in comments:

```
s.decode('ascii', errors='ignore')
```