# How can I remove multiple special characters from a string?

Tags: python, list, special-characters

I'm going to be comparing user input to the values in a list that I have, say a list called `names`. What's the best way to remove special characters, such as periods(.), hyphens(-), and/or apostrophes(') so that I can compare them with the list `names`?

So for instance, my list would be somewhat similar to this:

```
names = ["john", "mike", "mark", "obrien", "lisamarie"]
```

Now let's say the user enters **Lisa-Marie** or **O'Brien**. How can I convert the user input into **lisamarie** or **obrien**?

Thanks for your help, guys! :)

Comment: `str.translate()` and `str.lower()`.

Comment: You can also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843518/remove-all-special-characters-punctuation-and-spaces-from-string).