# Create new dataFrame based on reformatted columns from old dataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I imported the data from a database

```
df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri",
"mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.db").load()
```

I have selected the double columns using

```
double_list = [name for name,types in df.dtypes if types == 'double']
```

Credits to @Ramesh Maharjan.
To remove special characters we use

```
removedSpecials = [''.join(y for y in x if y.isalnum()) for x in double_list]
```

The question is:

How can I create a new dataframe based on `df` with ONLY `double_list` columns. ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan the other one is to just get the datatype of a column, this question is 'creating a new dataframe in pyspark based on the datatype of the column'

Comment: @RameshMaharjan no, I am afraid not. My question is how to remove special characters from column type double. I already know how to print the schema and find the double columns. The question is how to create a new dataframe, based on the columns double.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan No worries, I was not clear enough. I slighly modified the question.

Comment: so you just want to rename with the special characters removed on the column names that have double as datatype . is that correct?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes, you are on point !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *already have list of column names with double as datatype* then next step is to remove the special characters which can be done by using `.isalnum()` [credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5843560/5880706) as

```
removedSpecials = [''.join(y for y in x if y.isalnum()) for x in double_list]
```

once you have the special characters removed list of column names then its just `.withColumnRenamed()` api call as

```
for (x, y) in zip(double_list, removedSpecials):
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(x, y)
```

`df.show(truncate=False)` should give you the renamed dataframe on the columns with double datatype

If you don't want the columns that are not in double_list i.e. not in double datatype list then you can use select as

```
df.select(*removedSpecials).show(truncate=False)
```

The reason for doing

```
for (x, y) in zip(double_list, removedSpecials):
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(x, y)
```

before doing

```
df.select(*removedSpecials).show(truncate=False)
```

is that there might be *special characters* like `.` which doesn't make concise solutions like `df.select([df[x].alias(y) for (x, y) in zip(double_list, removedSpecials)]).show(truncate=False)` to work

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: `df = df.withColumnRenamed(x,y)` will now also have columns that were NOT in the `double_list`. The idea is to create a new dataFrame with only the `double_list` columns. All other columns that are not in `double_list` are dropped.

Comment: so you don't want the columns that are not in double_list?

Comment: I do not want the columns that are not in `double_list´

Comment: I am trying to pass `df.select(*removedSpecials)` to a new variable, but simply doing `df_new = df.select(*removedSpecials)` does not seem to do the trick. Is there a way to create a new independent copy variable from the original dataframe with only those columns ?

Comment: actually, I misunderstood the error. Here it is **Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Values to assemble cannot be null** . The next step will be to drop all empty and blank columns from the `df.select(*removedSpecials)`. Phew ! gotta figure that out.

Comment: try it. if you can't then research on the web and I know you can get a lot of infos in stackoverflow itself. If all of them fails, you are always welcome for another question

Answer (score 0):

scala code, you can convert into python

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
// sample df
df.show()
+----+--------------------+--------+
|data|                Week|NumCCol1|
+----+--------------------+--------+
| aac|01/28/2018-02/03/...|     2.0|
| aac|02/04/2018-02/10/...|    23.0|
| aac|02/11/2018-02/17/...|   105.0|
+----+--------------------+--------+

df.printSchema()

root
 |-- data: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Week: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NumCCol1: double (nullable = false)

 val df1 = df.schema.fields
      .collect({case x if x.dataType.typeName == "double" => x.name})
      .foldLeft(df)({case(dframe,field) => dframe.select(field)})

 // df with only double columns
 df1.show()
```

use `df1.withColumnRenamed` to rename the columns