# Python - Removing special character from string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have this below text and I am trying to remove the special character shown in the image using Python.

[image]

**Update (pasting the text):**

```
145,Kevin,07/06/2018 15:12:37,Kevin,nan,nan,"have to clear outstanding tasks. 
check schedule "
```

I tried the below but had no luck

```
DF['col'] = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", str(DF['col']))
```

Could anyone assist on this. Thanks..

Comment: The image can't help, please copy/paste the actual text into the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, when I try to copy paste the special character does not show up. Rather it only shows an empty space. That was the reason to give a screenshot of the text.

Comment: Good, let us see the "space", add the text.

Comment: You can take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843518/remove-all-special-characters-punctuation-and-spaces-from-string

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew have updated the message with the text

Comment: You lost the original text I believe, there is no special chars here. Do not try to format the text. Copy it exactly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, when I paste the text the part that has the special character gets replaced with an empty space and the remaining text gets written on the next line.. I did not change anything when I pasted the text

Comment: try re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ", str(DF['col']))

Comment: If it is a line break, remove the line break - `DF['col'] = DF['col'].str.replace(r'\r?\n', '')`

Comment: To remove all control chars, try https://ideone.com/xLm9wu

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missed out a +

try

```
DF['col'] = re.sub("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", " ", str(DF['col']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re,string
s='145,Kevin,07/06/2018 15:12:37,Kevin,nan,nan,"have to clear outstanding tasks. ♔ \ncheck schedule '
punc=re.escape(string.punctuation)
re.sub(fr"[^\w\s{punc}]","",s)
Out:
'145,Kevin,07/06/2018 15:12:37,Kevin,nan,nan,"have to clear outstanding tasks.  \ncheck schedule '
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['col'] = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+',' ',str(df['col'])
```

If you want to apply the function to all the rows, you might do:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].map(lambda x: re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+',' ',str(df['col'])))
```