# strip or remove all special characters from list of strings in python

Tags: python

I have list of strings and I have to remove all special characters (, - ' " .).

My code is

```
import glob
import re

files = []
for text in glob.glob("*.txt.txt"):
 with open(text) as f:
    fileRead = [ line.lower() for line in f]
 files.append(fileRead)

files1 = []

for item in files :
 files1.append(''.join(item))
```

I have used lot of options including "replace", "strip" and "re".

when I use strip (shown below), the code runs but no changes are seen in output.

```
files1 = [line.strip("'") for line in files1]
```

When I use re, I get TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.
I changed to list of strings from list of lists so that I can use re. This method is stated many times but did not solve the problem for me.

```
files1 = re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,]", "", files1)
```

I am not able to use replace as it throws an attribute error that replace cannot be used on lists.

Please suggest me how can I get rid of all special characters.

Comment: are you using python3 or python2.7?

Comment: `files1` is a list, not string.  You need to pass a string to `re.sub`.  So try element-wise.

Comment: @machetazo I am using python 3.

Comment: @KotaMori I have tried that too -  is there anything in this?
files1 = [re.sub('[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,]', '', files1) for y in files1]

Comment: Pass `y` not `files`?  If you still get error, provide the result of `type(files1[0])`

Comment: @KotaMori Thanks a lot! That worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all special characters, punctuation and spaces from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843518/remove-all-special-characters-punctuation-and-spaces-from-string)

Answer (score 4):

You should apply the re.sub function on single objects, not on lists.

```
files_cleaned = [re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,]", "", file) for file in files]
```

If you only want to accept alphanumerical characters you can do this instead:

```
files_cleaned = [re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "", file) for file in files]
```

Answer (score 0):

try below example:

```
files = ["Hello%","&*hhf","ddh","GTD@JJ"]    #input data in list

# going through each element of list
# apllying a filter on each character of string for alphabet or numeric other then special symbol
# joining the charactors back again and putting them in list
result = ["".join(list(filter(str.isalnum, line))) for line in files]

print(result)    #print the result
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'hhf', 'ddh', 'GTDJJ']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.isalnum`

will return True if all the character in the str are Alpha numeric.