# How to remove special characters from csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-cleaning

Currently cleaning data from a csv file. Successfully mad everything lowercase, removed stopwords and punctuation etc. But need to remove special characters. For example, the csv file contains things such as 'CÃ©sar' 'â€˜disgraceâ€™'. If there is a way to replace these characters then even better but I am fine with removing them. Below is the code I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()

pd.read_csv('soccer.csv', encoding='utf-8')
df = pd.read_csv('soccer.csv')

df.columns = ['post_id', 'post_title', 'subreddit']
df['post_title'] = df['post_title'].str.lower().str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '').str.split()


stop = stopwords.words('english')

df['post_title'] = df['post_title'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])

df['post_title']= df['post_title'].apply(lambda x : [lemma.lemmatize(y) for y in x])


df.to_csv('clean_soccer.csv')
```

Comment: Quite a few answers around, take a look e.g. to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5843547/3519000). Cheers.

Comment: can you actually post a sample df ?

Comment: try that: `df.to_csv('clean_soccer.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig)` or just `utf-8`

Comment: @VnC Thank you so much that's worked.

Comment: I'll post as an answer so you can approve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When saving the file try:

```
df.to_csv('clean_soccer.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

or simply

```
df.to_csv('clean_soccer.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an easy way to replace the special characters, but I know how you can remove them. Try using:

```
df['post_title']= df['post_title'].str.replace(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '')
```

That should replace 'CÃ©sar' 'â€˜disgraceâ€™' with 'Csardisgrace'. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to other answers, you could use `string.printable`:

```
import string

printable = set(string.printable)

def remove_spec_chars(in_str):
    return ''.join([c for c in in_str if c in printable])

df['post_title'].apply(remove_spec_chars)
```

For reference, `string.printable` varies by machine, which is a combination of digits, ascii_letters, punctuation, and whitespace.

For your example string `CÃ©sar' 'â€˜disgraceâ€™'` this function returns `'Csardisgrace'`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html
[How can I remove non-ASCII characters but leave periods and spaces using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689795/how-can-i-remove-non-ascii-characters-but-leave-periods-and-spaces-using-python)