# How to extract specific strings from string, for each row in a dataframe; and count for each item

Tags: python, pandas, string, lambda

So I have a df that looks like this:

```
Text     
___________________________
Hello, Jim.

I knew it was Sam! Sam why?!
```

I have a known list of names I want to extract from each row if they appear, and append that to a new column.

I have used this code to extract the names:

```
t = []
df['text'].apply(lambda x: t.append([char for char in chars if char in x]))
df['characters'] = t
```

Which results in:

```
Text                         |Characters
_____________________________|____________
Hello, Jim.                  |[Jim]
                             |
John said it was Sam! Bad Sam|[John,Sam]
```

But as you can see, it hasn't counted both occourances of 'Sam'. I want it to look like this:

```
Text                         |Characters
_____________________________|____________
Hello, Jim.                  |[Jim]
                             |
John said it was Sam! Bad Sam|[John,Sam,Sam]
```

Then I will be able to so a simple count for each item in the list for each row.

I'm not super familiar with lambda functions, and alot of this doesn't feel very efficient.

Any ideas?

Edit:

I can do this to get a count of one specific name for each row:

```
df['char_count'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.count('Sam'))
```

But not sure how to pass in the list in the column I have generated.

Comment: I realise I changed my example text half way - please discount this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form a regex out of your list of names and let pandas find all:

```
names = ["Sam", "Jim"]

pattern = fr"\b({'|'.join(names)})\b"    

df["Character"] = df.Text.str.findall(pattern)
```

The [regex](https://regex101.com/r/V2pSeD/1) `\b(Sam|Jim)\b` looks for either `Sam` or `Jim` (but standalone thanks to `\b` and @ShubhamSharma!). With `findall`, search is global per row.

to get

```
                           Text   Character
0                   Hello, Jim.       [Jim]
1  I knew it was Sam! Sam why?!  [Sam, Sam]
```

Comment: You can also add boundary condition in regex pattern to make sure the pattern does not matches partial words for e.g. you could do `fr"\b({'|'.join(names)})\b"`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that happens because Sam! is not the same as Sam. One solution would be to [delete all special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843518/remove-all-special-characters-punctuation-and-spaces-from-string) from the string value before comparing all words to your list of names.

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('\W', '')
t = []
df['text'].apply(lambda x: t.append([char for char in chars if char in x]))
df['characters'] = t
```

Comment: I have tries that and it isn't the case.