# Discord mp3 downloader security concerns

Tags: python, discord.py, yt-dlp

So i'm writing a python discord bot that uses yt-dlp to download a song then send it to a discord channel. Problem is, I need to save the mp3 to a path to reupload it, but i think my code would be vulnerable to an attack where someone does a youtube video with "../../../etc/[something]" in the title, and I don't really know how I'd be able to correct that.

What I ended up doing was using `'restrictfilenames': True` in my options. That way, it restrics all non standard characters from the filename that is saved

Here's the code.

```
@client.command()
async def dl(ctx, arg):
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        # ydl.download([arg])
        info = ydl.extract_info(arg)
    await ctx.send("ok goude", file=discord.File(download_path + info['title'] + '.mp3'))
```

Thanks to any help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to prevent "/" character.
You can do it using with replace the title:

```
title="/usr/bin/attack.mp3"
title=title.replace("/", "_")
```

If you want to include all special characters, you can look at this answer:
[Remove all special characters, punctuation and spaces from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843518/remove-all-special-characters-punctuation-and-spaces-from-string)