# What is the fastest and simplest way to remove "\" from a string

Tags: python, string, strip

when im parsing a lot of data with python and it can happen that some parts of the data contains strings/chars with `\`, this can lead to problems when working with the data so my goal is minimize errors by removing all kinds of special characters from the data

for example it could be a string like this

```
teststring = "\\ds9205343h\test" 
teststring2 = "\\ds9205343h\SOM-User"
```

I thought maybe strip () could easily solve that but it seems with strip i only remove

`\\`

but not `\`

```
teststring.strip("\\") # ofc strip("\") wont work 
teststring2.strip("\\")
```

print (teststring) would than print "\ds9205343h  est"
print (teststring2) would print "\ds9205343h\SOM-User"

The wanted Output for teststring is ds9205343htest and for teststring2 it is ds9205343hSOM-User

I think i can do it with regex but that does not seem very pythonic and efficient to me, any ideas how to solve this in a pythonic way ?

the User @Timeless has provided following solution in the comments:

```
f"{teststring!r}".replace("\\", "").strip("'")
```

I tested it on my dataset and it worked

Comment: `\test` will print `tab` and `est`, not `\test`. What is the expected output anyway?

Comment: Viewing the source of the question reveals a formatting error but it's really not clear if the OP means "remove `\\ ` but keep `\ `" or something else. Regardless, this is almost certainly a duplicate; please search before asking.

Comment: i want to remove all wether its "\"  or "\\"  i did search ofc i found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843518/remove-all-special-characters-punctuation-and-spaces-from-string

Comment: You can effectively remove characters from a string by replacing them with an empty string. If you have multiple substitutions to carry out then take a look at *str.maketrans* and *str.translate*

Comment: and yes it seems '\' makes formatting issues, edited the post so the '\' are actually shown

Comment: there are over 100K Data Entries every day from mail that i put into a databse and than i read from a Database, it worked perfectly fine until someone give a machine an name  with lots of '\' in it , i already changed the machine names, but i want to make the system fool proof for the future so this won't happen again

Comment: @timless  yes this seems to work for the given example it then returns ds9205343htest

Comment: @9769953 yes the step where i try to remove '\' is when reading mails, the Problem occurs in another module where i work with the data

Comment: @9769953 i mean it is unlikely but as long as humans are part of the process it could happen i now tried the solution given by CrtlZ and added '(r""+(str(splitString[0]))).replace("\\","")' to my code it worked , does this have some case where it won't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use str.replace() **but** you need to understand how you would construct a string to contain backslashes.

Consider this example:

```
teststring_1 = r"\\ds9205343h\test"
teststring_2 = "\\ds9205343h\test"

for s in teststring_1, teststring_2:
    print(s)
    print(s.replace("\\", ""))
    print()
```

Note that test string_1 is a raw string. It will contain 3 backslashes.

teststring_2 is a regular string and so each single backslash is potentially an escape character. This string will contain 1 backslash because the \t sequence is interpreted as a tab character whereas \\ is the means by which a string can include a backslash.

Now consider the output of this code:

```
\\ds9205343h\test
ds9205343htest

\ds9205343h     est
ds9205343h      est
```

Comment: thanks for the insight i know remember and i a, bit ashamed of myself, this seems to be basic knowledge you should know, i worked alot with strings etc. but this problem never occured for me maybe because most of the time it  is natural speech i do analyze where no one uses '\' in the shown way, this task i did here was more of analyzing machines etc