# Python how to initialize thread with unknown number of arguments?

Tags: python, multithreading, iterable-unpacking

I'm having trouble using the starred expressions in combination with fixed argument lists when attempting to create threads.

Consider the following code:

```
the_queue = Queue()

def do_something(arg1, arg2, queue):
    # Do some stuff...
    result = arg1 + arg2

    queue.put(result)

def init_thread(*arguments):
    t = Thread(target=do_something, args=(arguments, the_queue))
    t.start()
    t.join()

init_thread(3,6)
```

This throws the exception:

```
TypeError: do_something() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

In other words, the "arguments" tuple is evaluated as one tuple object (i.e. it's not unpacked), and the_queue is regarded as the second argument.

The code needs to be able to initalize threads calling different methods with an unknown number of arguments, but that always will have a "queue" parameter at the end.

Is there any way to achieve this? In that case, how? And if not -- what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: I should add that calling the "init_thread()" method with the queue as an argument is not an option, since I don't want the rest of my code to be "aware" of how the thread handler works internally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a new `tuple`.

```
t = Thread(target = do_something, args = arguments + (the_queue, ))
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I didn't know you could concatenate a tuple to another one that way. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can also unpack the packed-up *arguments tuple, like so:

```
>>> def Print(*args):
...     print('I am prepended to every message!', *args)
... 
>>> Print('This', 'has', 'four', 'arguments')
I am prepended to every message! This has four arguments
>>> def Print(*args):
...     print('I am prepended to every message!', args)
... 
>>> Print('This', 'has', 'four', 'arguments')
I am prepended to every message! ('This', 'has', 'four', 'arguments')
```

So you see, referring to *agruments, as opposed to arguments, will unpack the tuple.
Thus your code might be:

```
def init_thread(*arguments):  
    t = Thread(target=do_something, args=(*arguments, the_queue))
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

Comment: I actually tried writing it that way first (with *arguments to unpack) but I get an error when trying to do it. I've tried it in python 2.6 and python 3.2.2. In which version of Python is that legal? It certainly is a useful feature which I thought was missing when facing my problem...
Edit: The error is "can use starred expression only as assignment target"

Comment: I have no idea. I use Python 3.2. A quick Google turned up some similar problems here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870778/why-does-this-cause-a-syntax-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967819/python-when-can-i-unpack-a-generator I guess it's just unfortunate that there's the extra set of parens. One of those links suggested the same solution as the first answer here.